# Angular router different routes same component keep component instance

Tags: angular, router

I know that if you navigate to and from the same route, by default Angular will keep the same component instance (even ignoring the navigation event).

But I wanna know if there's is a standard way of having this behavior when navigating to a different route but that it uses the same component than the previous route, so completing the navigation but keeping the same component instance as there isn't any change visually.

I've seem usage of `RouteReuseStrategy` but I don't know if that is for this purpose since I haven't seen a solution with that.

I would like to know if this can be achieved by standard means like that or not, before starting to look for a hacky way of achieving it.

Comment: if this is the issues with one component only then in that component 
try subscribe to route event and have a code in case of navigation end hit import function of that component. to reuse it

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, but please, do not simply throw out arrows to hit the target by chance and assume I know the basics.
In navigation events you cannot control the rendered component. I don't want to reuse something a function does (that is plain simple). I want to reuse the component instance, as the question explains. No need go anywhere else.